# Can't set Xfce4 as default in SLiM (Simple Login Manager)

Tags: linux, debian

I'm running SLiM 1.3.4-2 on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian. I have Xfce4 and LXDE installed. When SLiM shows up it says `Session: default` and when I run that LXDE starts. I want Xfce4 as default.

I've tried adding

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/startxfce4
```

To .xinitrc and doing `chmod +x ~/.xinitrc` (which I had to create, because there was no .xinitrc), but that does not help. I've tried adding only `DEFAULT_SESSION=startxfce4` to .xinitrc. I have also tried removing `default` from the `sessions` variable in `/etc/slim.conf` but LXDE stays default when I just log in via SLiM without pressing F1 to pick `startxfce4`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a statement similar to this one in your `~/.xinitrc` file.

```
# Adapted from: http://svn.berlios.de/svnroot/repos/slim/trunk/xinitrc.sample

case $1 in
kde)
    exec startkde
    ;;
xfce4)
    exec startxfce4
    ;;
wmaker)
    exec wmaker
    ;;
blackbox)
    exec blackbox
    ;;
icewm|*)
    icewmbg &
    icewmtray &
    exec icewm
    ;;
esac
```

**Note**: In the latest version (1.3.5), **SLiM does not preset any default session**, so using a `DEFAULT_SESSION variable will not work the way it used to`. Instead put your default session as the last case and **`|*)`** to the statement (see above).

<sub>[More Info](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM)</sub>

Comment: Yes, but as noted I'm running 1.3.4-2. It was the latest version for me to get when doing an `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade slim`. I did this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6971683
And it did not work.
(Sorry for external code. I couldn't quite figure out how to get a code block in this reply. Indented with 4 spaces, but it does nothing.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the version of your SLiM - from ArchWiki

> Note: SLiM no longer supports a 'default' session where multiple sessions have been enabled. This is most noticable where attempting to log out and back in again to the same session.

You can't get a default session currently, you either put in your `.xinitrc` file:

```
exec startxfce4
```

or select the session by pushing the F1 key each time you attempt to log in.

It is not needed to make the huge case statement above:

```
DEFAULTSESSION=startxfce4
if [ "$1" = "" ] 
then exec $DEFAULTSESSION
else exec  $1
fi
```

would do the job.

Comment: [Slim Options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM#All_Slim_Options), as you can see, there's no default session option in all slim available configurations (edit your /etc/slim.conf file), i suspect - the order of the session list in slim depends of the method that slim grabs it from the /usr/share/xsession (or similar on your os) directory